# Issue regarding copying data from second stored value _Ty2 second of a std::map iterator

Tags: c++, windows

I am using visual studio 2008 as compiler. I have a std map which contains first parameter as std::string and second parameter as struct CSVFileInfo. I tried to copy the iterator second parameter to an another object of CSVFileInfo using memcpy function as follows,

```
std::map<std::string, CSVFileInfo>::iterator iter;
for(iter = csv_files.begin(); iter != csv_files.end(); iter++)
{
  CSVFileInfo objCsv;
  memcpy(&objCsv, &(iter->second), sizeof(CSVFileInfo));
}
```

which resulted in a crash in release mode but not in debug mode. My struct is as follows,

```
    struct CSVFileInfo 
    {
        typedef boost::thread _csv_run_thread_;
        bool m_outofService;
        bool m_readonly;
        bool m_is_running;
        int m_start_option;
        HTREEITEM m_item;
        std::string m_fileNamePath;
        std::string m_file;
        CCSVHandler* m_csvHandler;
        _csv_run_thread_ *m_thread;

        CSVFileInfo() : m_outofService(false), m_readonly(false), m_thread(NULL),
            m_is_running(false), m_csvHandler(NULL), m_item(NULL), m_start_option(100)
        {
        }
    };
```

When i found the crash i changed my code to,

```
    CSVFileInfo csvFileInfo;
    csvFileInfo.m_csvHandler = iter->second.m_csvHandler;
    csvFileInfo.m_file = iter->second.m_file;
    csvFileInfo.m_fileNamePath = iter->second.m_fileNamePath;
    csvFileInfo.m_is_running = iter->second.m_is_running;
    csvFileInfo.m_item = iter->second.m_item;
    csvFileInfo.m_outofService = iter->second.m_outofService;
    csvFileInfo.m_readonly = iter->second.m_readonly;
    csvFileInfo.m_start_option = iter->second.m_start_option;
    csvFileInfo.m_thread = iter->second.m_thread;
```

instead of the memcpy function. I fixed the issue.

My doubt is regarding the crash, why memcpy gave a crash when i used it in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems is that you use `std::memcpy` to copy objects. This should be solved by doing simple copy-construction (or even assignment), if you really *need* a copy:

```
CSVFileInfo objCsv = iter->second;
```

If you don't actually need a copy, use references instead:

```
CSVFileInfo &objCsv = iter->second;
```

---

Using `std::memcpy` is troublesome because it's basically does a byte-wise copy, disregarding the C++ copy-semantics (copy-construction, copy-assignment). That will be very problematic when using other classes inside your class, like the `std::string` members as they will not be copied correctly.

Using C++ copy-semantics will solve this problem.

In general, unless you have a C-style [POD object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) you should avoid C-style functions for manipulating the object (e.g. `memcpy` or `memset` and more).

Comment: I actually used C based memcpy, not the std::memcpy. You can see that i have not used any using keyword. This code base was an old one and many have worked on this code. Since both C and C++ programmers have worked on the code it is a mixture of both. Even i thought of changing the struct to a class but then found the above code solved the issue and kept it like that.

Comment: @SujithkVarghese If you're programming C++, then `memcpy` and `std::memcpy` is the same. Especially if you have `using namespace std;`.

Comment: The code base doesn't contain using namespace std; Apart from that are you  saying memcpy and std::memcpy are the same? Please confirm, thank you for the support.

Comment: @SujithkVarghese Even without the `using namespace std;` they are the same. If you include `<string.h>` instead of `<cstring>`, then the symbols from that header file are put in the global namespace automatically. `std::memcpy` and the global `memcpy` functions are the same.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the clarification and the support.